# Displaying component based on prop value react

Tags: reactjs, components, react-props, conditional-rendering

I have four components Rectangle, Circle, Triangle, Star.
Based on the value that the user gave in props I want to return the component. For example, If the user gave a prop as a Rectangle, I want to display the Rectangle Component.
I don't want to use the If-Else statement every time checking for all four conditions. Is there a better option?

Ex: Rectangle Component

```
import React from "react";

function Rectangle(props) {
  return (
    <div className="term">
      <svg width="400" height="110">
        <rect
          width="300"
          height="100"
          stroke="black"
          stroke-width="3"
        />
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Rectangle;
```

Can anybody please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't want to use `If-Else`, you could consider `switch`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a static mapping for `shape type -> Component`. E.g. assuming the shape type is provided in a prop `shape`:

```
const Shapes = {
    rectangle: Rectangle,
    circle: Circle,
    triangle: Triangle,
    star: Star,
};

const Shape = ({shape, ...props}) => {
    const ActualShape = Shapes[shape];

    return <ActualShape {...props} />;
};
```

Example Usage:

```
<Shape shape="circle" r="10" stroke="red" />
<Shape shape="rectangle" stroke="black" width="300" height="100" />
```

Comment: Thank you for replying!Im new to web develpment. Can u please tell me what does those three dots mean?